# Keep SelectedItem during filter of CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, .net-4.0

I have a listbox that is being filter like this:

```
var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(FilterSource);
view.Filter = FilterCode;
```

I am running into a problem where the `SelectedItem` is getting lost when the filter is used with viewmodel code like this:

```
VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Items{get;set;}
    public Model SelectedItem
    {
        get{return _selectedItem;}
        set{_selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged();}
    }
}
```

When the filter is applied, the `SelectedItem` is set to `null`. However, I want to keep that selected item unless the user actually clicks off of it. If the filter is removed, then the selected item should still be selected. The Model does have an `IsSelected` property, and I have been trying to think of ways to query for the `IsSelected` property. However, then the view's binding would not work the way I expect....or at least I am going in circles thinking it cannot

Comment: if your collection has somekind of primary key you can save this id before filtering and try to set the selecteditem with this id after filtering

Answer (score 1):

My only way of accomplishing a fix here is the following in the `SelectionChanged` event:

```
if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0 && e.RemovedItems.Count >= 0)
    SpecialtyListBox.SelectedItem = e.RemovedItems[0];
```

But, this seems really hacky and forces that there must always be an item selected once an initial one is selected. In this case, that might work, but I would still like to see if anybody has a better solution?

Comment: Definitely hacky-feeling, however I actually did have this requirement. I had a list of things, and 1 (and only 1) is always selected. So this solution actually worked out perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by creating a filter that always adds the current selected item to the filtered items. If this cannot be done directly, just hold the selected item in a separate variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where the listboxes were shown as tabbed views.  I solved the problem by creating a Converter to produce a Boolean flag for "isActive" and assigning it to CollectionViewSource.IsLiveFilteringRequested.  This prevented the non-active list boxes from updating the selected item.