# How to keep the SelectedItem in CollectionView filtering?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So essentially I've a `ListView` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="Contacts" ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}" 
          SelectionChanged="Contacts_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Contact, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

the filter is applied in this way:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Contacts.ItemsSource).Filter = GeneralUtility.FilterMethod;
```

Now when the user select a contact the app fill all controls with the contact information. When the user search a contact using the filter, the `SelectedItem` will be lost with the item searched.

The `Contacts` binded is a list:

```
 public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

and the `SelectedItem` is the contact selected:

```
private Contact _contact;
//Current contact selected
public Model Contact
{
    get { return _contact; }
    set 
    {
        _contact = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

a practice example:

```
 > User select the item on the contacts list
 > User search a contact on the list
 > The filter cause the selecteditem to change <-- problem here
```

as you can see, I need to prevent the last step to change the selecteditem automatically (only the user can change the selected contact).

any idea or solution to keep the SelectedItem of the user?

Comment: What happens to the SelectedItem? Does it appear empty or does it default to some other value?

Comment: @Jack if the user select a contact called foo, when him search another contact, for example foo2, the filtering set as SelectedItem foo2, but I need to keep foo

Comment: This is a normal behavior. The ListView can only select what is shown, but through the filter the previous selected item is not longer populated to the ListView.

Comment: @Rabban I know, I could fix this by creating another property and hardcode the selection_changed event, but I was looking for another and more elegant solution

Comment: Did you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17100603/keep-selecteditem-during-filter-of-collectionviewsource)

Comment: @deafjeff yep, but no answers...

Comment: You can save the selected object in the ViewModel. Then you will have to manage the selection manually (no direct bind with SelectedItem). I think it is possible to tell the difference between a selection change by click, and a selection change by other way.